# Android App for split screen pdf note taking (for tablets)

Tags: applications, google-play-store, tablet, pdf, notes

Does anybody know of an app which lets you have a split screen of pdf(left) and note taking blank page(right) setting, so that you can make notes for every individual page? When you revisit it would show the pdf page and its corresponding note. I know of the Boox Note e-ink reader being able to do this and some iOS apps such as Easy-annotate or Flexcil. Is there also perhaps an app like these for android?

Thanks.